# tumblr API fetch post's comments

Tags: php, api, tumblr

```
 <?php
 $numPosts = 5;

  $feedURL = "http://#######.tumblr.com/api/read/?num=$numPosts";

   $xml = @simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

  foreach(@$xml->posts->post as $post){
  $posts = (string) $post->{'photo-caption'}; 
  $img = (string) $post->{'photo-url'};
   echo "<div style='width:518px;height:600px;'><div style='width:518px;height:200px;  float:left;'>".'<img style="width:200px;height:200px;" src="' . $img . '" />'."</div><div style='width:518px;height:300px;float:left;'>".$posts."</div></div><br>";}

 ?>
   <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
var disqus_shortname = 'creativescripters'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

// The following are highly recommended additional parameters. Remove the slashes in front to use.
 var disqus_identifier = 'unique_dynamic_id_1234';
var disqus_url = 'http://creativescripters.com/samples/tab/tab7.html';

/* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
(function() {
    var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
    dsq.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
})();
```

Here i am fetching the posts, but i want to fetch comments that are given to a particular post..

Comment: can someone answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments in Tumblr are known as notes.

See the [API documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2) - /posts - section for details.

For your specific question, you just have to set the Boolean `notes_info` to true on API request. For example:

General API post request
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/peacecorps.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key=PyezS3Q4Smivb24d9SzZGYSuhMNPQUhMsVetMC9ksuGPkK1BTt&notes_info

API request for post with notes
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/peacecorps.tumblr.com/posts/text?api_key=PyezS3Q4Smivb24d9SzZGYSuhMNPQUhMsVetMC9ksuGPkK1BTt&notes_info=true

So just change your feed URL and you should be good to go.

Comment: Can you be bit more specific, what exactly i have to do.

Comment: Looks like you are using the old version of the API. See the link in my answer for details of the new version. I am not sure if the old API allows you to read the notes.

Comment: Your current code will not work with the new API (if thats what you are planning to do). You get a JSON feed from tumblr which you need to parse to access the posts and notes.